# Why doesn't cin re-prompt if input value exceeds target type size?

Tags: c++, cin

I noticed while I was implementing a simple linked-list stack that `cin` doesn't re-prompt if I enter a value larger than the max. size of an integer. For example:

```
int input;
do {
    cin >> input;
    if (input == -1)
        break;
    else if (input == 0)
        pop();
    else
        push(input);
} while (input != -1);
```

would loop forever if I entered a number which exceeds the size of an `int` (note that the type of `input` is `int`).

This is likely the most dangerous behaviour that I have encountered so far of a relatively well isolated C++ program in the short time that I have been programming in this language. Because the loop pushed the input on every iteration, my program's memory usage sharply increased to over 1GB in less than 30 seconds... my computer nearly crashed.

So I'm wondering: why would `cin` exhibit this behaviour?

P.S. I resolved this infinite-loop problem by adding `input = -1` before reading the input. Is this the best way to prevent the looping?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, didn't see that question. I guess my question is also touching on *why* `cin` behaves this way (or as referred to in the linked question put in a 'failed' state)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be checking the state of `cin` after reading from it. If the failbit is set, the input operation failed. You could re-prompt after that.

E.g., `if (!cin) { ... }`

Comment: Okay, what's the failbit?

Comment: It's a bit confusing the bits on streams: failbit, badbit, good(),etc but if you check the value of cin as a bool you'll see if the state is good.

Comment: P.S. sorry about the accidental pun "a *bit* confusing" on failbit, badbit, etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider re-writing like this:

```
int input;

while(!(std::cin >> input)) {
    cout << "you entered in the wrong type, please try again" << endl;
    cin.clear();// clear error flags from cin
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //extracts characters from the stream and discards them until a newline is found 
}

if(input == 0){
    pop();
}else{
    push(input);
}
```

Note that entering in a value that's larger than the maximum allowed `int` will cause the fail bit for `cin` to be set. This solution relies on this behaviour to work.

Answer (score 0):

Signed integer types just wrap around if you exceed their maximum value.

To counteract it you should only push the input to the stack if it is within the acceptable bounds